# how can we call the functions of second_activity in the main_activity by a radio button?

Tags: android

There are two activities, `Main_Activity` and `Configuration_activity`.

The `Configuration_activity` has radio buttons (vibrate, silent and normal modes)(also saving states) which works properly on phone.

Can I use the configuration of second activity in the `Main_Activity` by just clicking a single radio button in the Main_Activity?

The `Configuration_Activity` is already intent with `Main_activity` through an image button.

Comment: you want in main activity when created ,change Configuration_activity?@Owaiskhattak

Comment: thanks for reply,, no,, i have both activities , in configuration activity i have silent vibrate and normal radio buttons they work good in configuration_activity, but i want these configuration to click on one radio button in main_activity, already intent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can! By following the steps mentioned below:

1. Make the functions/methods (vibrate, silent and normal mode) public and static.
2. Make an object of *Configuration_activity* and call the function/method that you desire.

**Note:**
You can also use Shared Preference for saving the states.